# Creating directories from a web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, iis-7, permissions, file-permissions

I am using .NET MVC3 to create a website. which will be used to make some file operations at server machine. Right now I am in development process so i didn't have it on IIS. I am working on Visual studio 2010's development server. I am having trouble with creating a directory in App_Data folder. Users need to be able to create folders in App_Data(or somewhere appropriate)  and upload files in those folders. all users will be my friends so there is no security problem. But it says access denied :/ and i can't seem to find to grant related permissions. When i looked for it i found that granting "aspnet machine" user with read/write permissions would do it, but i don't have that user on my computer I don't know why:/ Should I move my application to IIS to make it? or is there any other thing that I don't know? By the way all my files in my pc are read only and i can't seem to change them neither:/ maybe it's because of that. But anyways i need a workaround for this issue.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Scenario: when you debugging your asp.net application from VS, your project running under "ASP.NET Development Server" tool (It means that tool has the same permissions as Visual Studio, also you may find it in tray);
2. Scenario: You may use FileMon from Sysinternals and see filesystem activities;
3. Scenario: Deploy to IIS and create new AppPool with your own user (grand permissions to App_Data directory).

Best Regards.